# Including C++ header files in Objective-C++ when they conflict with Objective-C macros

Tags: xcode, clang, objective-c++

In Xcode, I've created a "Cocoa application" project. One of its dependencies is a framework containing C++ code. I renamed AppDelegate.m to AppDelegate.mm and included the framework.

The project fails to compile. The problem is that the C++ header files in the framework are using some symbols that conflict with Objective-C or Cocoa.

- The C++ header files are defining functions called `verify()` and `check()`, which conflict with /usr/include/AssertMacros.h in the MacOSX10.8 SDK.
- The C++ header files contain a variable called `NO`, which conflicts with the Objective-C macro `NO`.

A workaround would be to modify the C++ code in the framework to avoid these conflicts. But since it's a large C++ project maintained by another organization, this would take time and would possibly break in future updates of the C++ project.

Is there some way just to tell Clang/Xcode to treat those C++ header files as C++ instead of Objective-C++?

Comment: Perhaps compiling with something along the lines `g++ -Dverify=vrfy -Dcheck=chk ...` so as to redefine those macros globally? (Just checked with `g++` here, it just complains on redefinition.)

Comment: Remember that C++ and Objective C are both supersets of C. The symbols you are getting conflicts on are C functions or macros, not Objective C functions or C++ functions. My point is, there is no such thing as an "Objective C function" or a "C++ function". A function may contain some Objective C or C++ specific stuff in it, but for the symbol itself there is no distinction. So the literal answer to your question is "no", but perhaps some of the workarounds people are mentioning in the answers will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the `/usr/include/AssertMacros.h` that comes with Mac OS 10.8, it looks like you could do:

```
#define __ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES 0
```

before including `AssertMacros.h`, which will prevent it from defining macros called `verify()` and `check()`.

Regarding `NO`: you could use the preprocessor to rename that variable for you.  For example:

```
#define NO NO_libraryname_renamed
#include <libraryname.hh>
#undef NO
```

Depending on how the `NO` variable is used by the library, this might cause problems — if the header is declaring it as `extern`, then your Cocoa app will refer to it by the wrong name, and you'll get an undefined symbol error.  But as long as you're not using that variable, and the library isn't depending on your app to define that variable, then you should be fine.

*(And please file a bug report with the offending library, requesting that they rename their variable.)*

Answer (score -4):

Mixing several languages *is* calling for grief. Even more so mixing Objective C++ (itself a strange hybrid) with C++. Don't do it.

Comment: Not an option. The application needs to be Cocoa. The C++ code is too big to rewrite.